# What package level access needed in Java for?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

In general what package level access needed in Java for? 
I can suggest only one reason:

1. Unit testing

Something else?

**UPD 1**

I know what is **package level access**. It's when any code from the same package can access. My question is: **why** this access level is needed? Why java creators invent this new level. I guess not for nothing but in purpose. What is the purpose?

**UPD2**

Actually the answer is found here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220053/why-did-java-make-package-access-default/220066#220066

Comment: 2. only classes from the same package have access

Comment: 3. [Allowing novice programmers to write sloppy code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220066/138701) is my favorite.

Comment: Think about it this way.....you are creating a library for other people to use that is called `ImageProcessor`.... when user's do stuff, they call `new ImageProcessor().process()`... do you want the user to be able to execute every method in the ImageProcessor class? No.... you only want them to access the public methods (the methods that are actually useful to them)

Comment: @azurefrog Thank you! upvoted that question as well as the answer!

Comment: @RobOhRob for the purpose you mention there is private access

Comment: @J.J.Beam, yes.... but what if you have a shared method that is useful to a bunch of classes in the same package? You don't want to user to see that? But you want to be able to share it

Comment: @RobOhRob, you just rephrased the concept of package level access: it's shared for package code but closed for outside. Sorry I expect a real case when it's needed. And moreover, since this is java concept I expect a real real strong reason and strong case why it's needed

Comment: @J.J.Beam if you group classes together in the same package, then they are probably related in some way....because they are related in some way, it makes sense that they may want to share data/functions ONLY between each other (classes in the same package)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use separate package in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043004/when-to-use-separate-package-in-java)

Comment: @J.J.Beam Well I'm not `rephrasing tautologically the concepts`, I'm giving you a simple answer to a simple question... Honestly you're just thinking too much into it

Comment: @RobOhRob honestly I was asked this question by interviewer and I don't think this is a simple question. It's a simple manner you try to use to answer it: "we need  package access when we need to write classes which can reach each other inside the package ONLY. "

Comment: @J.J.Beam lol yes....that is it... nothing more, nothing less

Comment: @RobOhRob Sorry, no. I need the root cause. I expected the answer which was provided by azurefrog, he found it here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220053/why-did-java-make-package-access-default/220066#220066

Comment: @J.J.Beam lol and while that answer is very informative, it answers `Why did Java make package access default?` Which is not what you were asking

Comment: @RobOhRob, OK the question "Why did Java make package access default?" is more deep than mine, actually there are 2 questions covered there: 1) why did Java make package access? 2) why the package access is default

Comment: Classes are there to interact. What use would a `private` class have? No-one could use it. So unless you want to make everything `public`, there must be an access level for classes that is distinct from `public` but not `private`, as that would make the class unusable. Say hello to package-level...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The package access is something that allows programmers to use their sloppy programming techniques while writing code within one package, but then they have to reconsider it when making more packages. It is a compromise between good business practices and the ugly reality. Like: write some spaghetti code, if you insist, but please leave the ugly mess within the package; at least create some nicer interfaces among the packages.

Comment: Lol is any of this in the actual java documentation? Cause honestly it's a decent answer, but it's all just speculation

Comment: @RobOhRob, if you want to learn java, read please the documentation here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much JJ. Much appreciated. I would like to share this with you also if you would like to learn more about package level access. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: It's a very nice tutorial, perfect for beginners!